# Trait with a callback: How to model argument reference lifetime?

Tags: rust, generic-associated-types, trait-bounds

Let's consider the following example of a trait involving an `FnOnce` callback (but I guess it's the same for `FnMut` or `Fn`):

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Holder<T>(Rc<RefCell<T>>);

trait Callback<A> {
    fn callback(&self, f: impl FnOnce(&A));
}

impl<A> Callback<A> for Holder<A> {
    fn callback(&self, f: impl FnOnce(&A)) {
        f(&self.0.borrow())
    }
}
```

So far this example allows to write code like this:

```rust
let holder_a = Holder(Rc::new(RefCell::new(42)));
holder_a.callback(|a| println!("{a}"));
```

My goal now is to generalize this pattern over tuples of `Holder`, i.e., I'd like to be able to do:

```rust
let holder_a = Holder(Rc::new(RefCell::new(42)));
let holder_b = Holder(Rc::new(RefCell::new(1.0)));
(holder_a, holder_b).callback(|(a, b)| println!("{a} {b}"));
```

and later extend it to larger tuples (perhaps with the typical limit of 12). So the general challenge here is that we have e.g. an `(Holder<A>, Holder<B>, Holder<C>)` and for the callback signature we have to provide a `(&A, &B, &C)` instance (I don't want to rely on `Copy` or `Clone`). Essentially the question is **how to model the lifetime of these `&`** in the elements?

##### Attempt 1

Here are a few naive attempts. In the implementation above, `Callback` uses `A` as the generic argument, while the `FnOnce` uses `&A`. One idea would be to turn this around, i.e., don't introduce the `&` in the trait already, but "pass it in" via the generic argument. This would lead to:

```rust
trait Callback<A> {
    fn callback(&self, f: impl FnOnce(A));
}

impl<A> Callback<&A> for Holder<A> {
    fn callback(&self, f: impl FnOnce(&A)) {
        f(&self.0.borrow())
    }
}

impl<A, B> Callback<(&A, &B)> for (Holder<A>, Holder<B>) {
    fn callback(&self, f: impl FnOnce((&A, &B))) {
        f((&self.0.0.borrow(), &self.1.0.borrow()))
    }
}
```

Basically the signatures look right, but the compiler complains: *impl has extra requirement `for<'a> impl FnOnce(&A): FnOnce(&'a A)`*. It sound like this is not allowed because the trait itself has no lifetime associated to the `FnOnce`, but the impls do.

##### Attempt 2

My next attempt was to go even more generic, and also pass in the lifetime:

```rust
trait Callback<'a, Args> {
    fn callback(&'a self, f: impl FnOnce(Args));
}

impl<'a, A> Callback<'a, &'a A> for Holder<A> {
    fn callback(&'a self, f: impl FnOnce(&'a A)) {
        f(&self.0.borrow())
    }
}

impl<'a, A, B> Callback<'a, (&'a A, &'a B)> for (Holder<A>, Holder<B>) {
    fn callback(&'a self, f: impl FnOnce((&'a A, &'a B))) {
        f((&self.0.0.borrow(), &self.1.0.borrow()))
    }
}
```

Almost: This time the relation between the trait and the impls is fine, and also the intended usage compiles. But, the compiler rightfully complains that the lifetime of the borrow doesn't last long enough (*creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use*). Indeed, I guess now `'a` corresponds to the lifetime of `&'a self` and the borrow is more short lived than that.

---

The question remains: How can I model these lifetimes `(&'a A, &'a B, ...)` correctly in such a case? Is there a neat trick leveraging GATs or HRTBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do that using both GAT and HRTB, but it won't necessarily be convenient:

```rust
trait Callback {
    type Param<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;
    fn callback(&self, f: impl for<'a> FnOnce(Self::Param<'a>));
}

impl<A> Callback for Holder<A> {
    type Param<'a> = &'a A where Self: 'a;
    fn callback(&self, f: impl FnOnce(&A)) {
        f(&self.0.borrow())
    }
}

impl<A, B> Callback for (Holder<A>, Holder<B>) {
    type Param<'a> = (&'a A, &'a B)
    where Self: 'a;
    fn callback(&self, f: impl for<'a> FnOnce((&'a A, &'a B))) {
        f((&self.0 .0.borrow(), &self.1 .0.borrow()))
    }
}
```

Comment: To some degree I had asked the question to get a better understanding of the interplay of GAT + HRTBs, and their syntactic subtleties. So even though the other solution may be fine in my case, this answer was very instructive. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem with fresh eyes, I noticed that it should be possible to pull the entire callback out into a generic argument, i.e.:

```rust
trait Callback<F> {
    fn callback(&self, f: F);
}

impl<A, F> Callback<F> for Holder<A>
where
    F: FnOnce(&A),
{
    fn callback(&self, f: F) {
        f(&self.0.borrow())
    }
}

impl<A, B, F> Callback<F> for (Holder<A>, Holder<B>)
where
    F: FnOnce((&A, &B)),
{
    fn callback(&self, f: F) {
        f((&self.0.0.borrow(), &self.1.0.borrow()))
    }
}
```

This makes everything compile. In a sense this circumvents the challenge of specifying these lifetimes, because the lifetimes only get instantiated on the impl level.

I'm not entirely sure of all implications of doing it like that though.

Comment: If this works for you, this is likely the best option.